# Cant Figure out what goes wrong in model binding ASP.NET Core + Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, data-binding, razor-pages, multi-select, selectlist

I'm trying to simply get my selected items populated to the bound property `SelectedDataSourceIDs`, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The view:

```
@page

@model ContosoUniversity.Pages.Analysis.IndexModel
@{
}

<h1>Analysis</h1>
<form asp-page-handler="Analyze" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="SelectedDataSourcesIDs" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="SelectedDataSourceIDs" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.DataSourceNameSL" multiple>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="SelectedDataSourceIDs" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Analyze" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The model class:

```
public class IndexModel : DataSourceResourcesCompaniesSelectListModel
{
    private readonly ContosoUniversity.Data.SchoolContext _context;
    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedDataSourceIDs { get; set; }
    private AnalysisContext _analysisContext;

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        PopulateDataSourceDropDownList(_context);
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint in `OnPost` and `SelectedDataSourceIDs` is always null.

**What I tried/tested**

1. In `OnGet()`, the `DataSourceNameSL` is correctly populated with `DataTextField = "Name"` and `DataValueField = "ID"`. I can see and select multiple ListItems
2. In the payload of the query, there are the IDs
3. The naming is correct
4. The `ModelState` is valid
5. In `OnPost()`, the `DataSourceNameSL` is null and `SelectedDataSourceIDs` is null
6. I've even tried changing the Type from `IEnumerable<int>` to `List<int>`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `[BindProperty]` attribute when dealing with model-binding in razor app.

```
[BindProperty]
public IEnumerable<int> SelectedDataSourceIDs { get; set; }
```

[image]

Comment: omg, I've tried everything and missed the most obvious thing. Thank you